# Why SVN Checkout showing system error?

Tags: svn

I need to download project from svn server.For this,I have my id and password to access.To download code from server:

1. I have create a folder in root directory of my local project,perform right click and select svn checkout.
2. URL of repository : example - http://sntbd.com/svn/talentb/
3. Checkout directory : C:\wamp\www\talentb

Clicking ok button,Its showing error after sometime :

> Error Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://sntbd.com/svn/talentb'
>
> Error : OPTIONS on 'svn/talentb' failed: 408 Request Time-out

Any Idea?

Comment: Check network connection. Can you connect to the server using your browser ? Is your server running on port 80 ?

Comment: Yes,I can connect successfully in my browser.And my local server also running in 80 port.

Comment: I wonder if your SVN server blocks any suspicious computer from accessing (e.g. computers not in whitelist)

Comment: May be,I dont have any idea.What to do now?

Comment: You are the administrator of the SVN server? Check settings & logs. If not, ask the admin.

Comment: No,I am not,what should I check in settings & logs